# How to run Groovy Script in Java

Tags: java, grails, groovy, groovyshell

I have a Java code and I want to run a groovy script in Java the problem is that the method I created returns allways null

This is my script inside an html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <script type="server/groovy">
        import com.daimler.Car
        def id = request.getParameter("id")
        car = Car.lookup(id)
    </script>
    <head>
        <title>${car.brand}</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 title="${car.brand}">${car.brand}</h1>
        <h2 data-if="car.ecoFriendly" title="${car.fuelType}">Fuel Type:
            ${car.fuelType}</h2>
        <div data-loop-model="car.models">Model: ${model}</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is my method to run the Script

```
   //the request parameter comes from the doGet method FYI
    public Object runScript(HttpServletRequest request) {

            GroovyShell groovyShell = new GroovyShell();

            try {
                Script script = groovyShell.parse(new File("templates/index.tpl"));
                Map bindings = script.getBinding().getVariables();
                //setting atributes in script here
                bindings.put("id",request);

                //run the script
                script.run();

                //getting object values after the script
                Object carObject = bindings.get("car");
                return carObject;

            } catch (CompilationFailedException | IOException ex) {
                java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(CarServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                //improve 
                return null;
            }
```

Comment: Does it return null because the catch? If yes what's the exception it traces ?

Comment: It is because of the directory on the index.tpl :/ What you think is the best option? parse the html and obtain the script as a string a then run it our there is another way to do it? I really need help in this

Comment: What do you mean with the directory? To me best option it's to use grails or ratpack framework

Comment: Can you show an example below using my code?

Comment: Sorry what are you trying to achieve? That isn't a groovy script, its a HTML document. Your code will fail either because it isn't on the classpath or because it is not valid groovy. Why would you parse a HTML to get out some groovy snippet? What purpose does the HTML document have? If you want to run only the groovy script, then make only that part available either via a file or String or whatever. Your 'runScript' method is already hard-coded to check for a specific output though so it isn't very clear what separations of concerns you've thought of here.